# sql - if create_et date smaller than specific date, then sum price

Tags: php, sql, sum

I have a payments table. names of the table fields:

```
id
company_id
paid
create_et (datetime)
```

I need if company_id = company_id and create_at < specificdate('Y-m-d') then sum(paid).

My query:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(paid) as paid FROM payments WHERE payments.company_id = $company_id AND CAST(payments.created_at AS date)  < $specificdate";
```

but it's not working. Help me please.
no error message but return null.

Comment: "not working" is not an error message or problem statement. What is going wrong? An error? Some unexpected behaviour? Also your example is incomplete - we don't have access to any sample data, nor to the values of your variables $company_id and $specifidate (which you _really_ ought to parameterise if you value the security of your data), so we can't double-check what the results ought to look like. It's quite hard to help you because we haven't got enough info. Please edit your question to include more of the relevant detail. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. `payments.created_at` in your query doesn't match the `create_et` field name stated in your question. Please make sure the information you give us is accurate and consistent, so we are not trying to solve problems which may not exist in reality (such as non-matching field names, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Cast your `$date` variable as date.  Also as noted in a comment above, your list of fields has `create_et` but your query has `created_at`.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(paid) as paid 
        FROM payments 
        WHERE company_id = $company_id 
          AND CAST(created_at AS date)  < CAST('$specificdate' AS date)";
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but look at the rest of my answer where I have set it to cast `$specificdate` as `date`.

Comment: See the screenshot I just added, the query I gave is good, so the issue must be with your PHP script.  Can you add the script to your question?